# How can we loop different base URLS instead of the default base URL and run functional tests?

Tags: selenium, grails, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing, geb

I’m Running my Geb tests with webdriver and I want to run all the functional tests looping different base URL’s instead of the static default base URL. Is there a way i can achieve this? All the functionalities for the URLS i wanted to loop will be same, so there will be no issues with test-cases .

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by using browser.setBaseUrl and data driven tables:

```
@Unroll
class NewTest extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "I see the correct stuff when i visit a url"(){

        when: "I visit a url"

            browser.setBaseUrl(baseUrl)
            def aPage = browser.to(APage)

        then: "I see what im meant to see"

            1 == 1

        where:

            baseUrl | _
            "http://www.google.com" | _
            "http://www.stackoverflow.com" | _
    }
}
```

Note that data tables must be 2 columns, so using an underscore after a pipe allows you to have a single column of data.

More info here:

http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

Note: I've assumed your using Geb + Spock.